# How would you compare the numeric values within two character columns to one another in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns, Grade and Percent. They're both character columns. Even if something looks like a number it's stored as character.

They both have either numeric grades (70, 85, 91) and letter grades (A+, B, C-).

There are some cases where the Grade and Percent columns have numeric grades (stored as character), but they're different. I want to identify those cases and flag them as mismatched.

I tried 
`CASE WHEN CAST(Grade as int) != CAST(Percent as int)`

and that failed, but hopefully it gives you a sense of what I'm trying to do...

---- separate question---

Also, separately, how would I make a statement that flags when a value includes a character? Instead of something like CASE WHEN GRADE IN (A+,A,A-,B+,B,B-...D+,F) how would I do a CASE WHEN GRADE LIKE.. to identify these?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Correct the data model and the problem goes away.  Letter grade should not be stored at all, as it can (should) always be derived from pct at run time.  And grade_pct should be a number, not a character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use `TO_NUMBER()` with a `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` (available from Oracle 12.2:

```
CASE WHEN 
    TO_NUMBER(grade DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) 
    <> TO_NUMBER(percent DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)
THEN 'mismatch' END
```

If one of the conversions fails, `TO_NUMBER()` returns `NULL`; nothing different (nor equal) than `NULL` so the condition is not fullfilled.

On the other hand, if both conversions fail, then the resulting values are compared; if they do not match, `'mismatch'` is returned.

In ealier versions, you can check if the strings contain only digit, then convert and compare:

```
CASE WHEN
    REGEXP_LIKE(grade, '^[0-9]+$')
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(percent, '^[0-9]+$')
    AND grade <> percent
THEN 'mismatch' END
```

This assumes that both columns contain integer values (not decimals), and that there is no special formating to handle like leading `0`s (which make the strings different while numbers are equivalent).

---

To check if a value contains any non-digit characters, you could do:

```
regexp_like(grade, '[^0-9]')
```

Comment: The regexp_like part worked for character values, but I get this error on the CASE WHEN code you provided: ORA-06550: line 13, column 39: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @ESIRMITS: which Oracle version are you running? This requires 12.2, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Oh, whoops... it's 12.1

Comment: @ESIRMITS: I updated my answer with a workaround for ealier versions.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from test where  regexp_like (grade,’^[^a-zA-Z]*s’) 
and 
regexp_like (percent,’^[^a-zA-Z]*s’) and grade<>percent;
```